# Is String to int Array conversion possible?

Tags: java

I've written that piece of code in which I scanned an integer suppose 121 and for dividing it into 3 part I make it a String and tried to convert it again by splitting.But I am not getting the way? Is there any simple way to make it so?

```
  public static void main(String []args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = scan.nextInt() ;
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i = 1 ; i<=n; i++){
         String s = Integer.toString(i);

          int[] c = Integer.parseInt(s.split("")); //Here's the problem
          int sm = 0 ;
          for(int x :c){
              sm +=x ;
          }
          System.out.print(sm+" ");
       }
   }
```

input = 12

expected output:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3

output : Main.java:14: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be 
         converted to String
         int[] c = Integer.parseInt(s.split(""));

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and stating what's your input and expected output vs. actual output. Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that you'll get an answer.

Comment: why convert it to a String in the first instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output would not even seem to need any integer to string conversion:

```
int n = scan.nextInt();
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i > 0) System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(1 + i % 9);
}
```

For an input of `n = 12`, this prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
```

Comment: Actually it is the `remainder operator`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). [Modula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula) is a language family from Nicholas Wirth.

Comment: @ScaryWombat No worries. Wasn't sure if it was just a typo to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the whole array to `parseInt()`. You need to parse each element individually:

```
int[] c = Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Or the old-fashioned way:

```
String[] chars = s.split("");
int[] c = new int[chars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    c[i] = Integer.parseInt(chars[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ***could*** map each character from the `String[]` (from the `split`) to an `int`, and then convert that to an `int[]`. Like,

```
int[] c = Arrays.stream(s.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

with no other changes, that produces (as requested)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
```

With input of "12".

Comment: That was such sortest way to get the answer  ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this using an IntStream.

```java
    int n = 12;
    int[] values = IntStream.range(0, n).map(i -> i % 9 + 1).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

Produces

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3]

for n = 12